# Make the Price of Associated Products required

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute

In the configurable product, how to make the **Price** of Associated Products **Required**? (When the price is null, don't make save action success and has some tips.)

---

Note:

The price is **not** in the edit page of Associated Products, because the price there does not working.

The price is in the **Associated Products tab** which is in the **configurable product**. You could see the image below for reference

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to rewrite **app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\super\config.phtml** file in your custom theme and add `required-entry` class in the input field.

Update below code

```
<input id="__id___pricing" type="text" <?php if ($this->isAttributesPricesReadonly() || $this->getCanEditPrice() === false): ?> disabled="disabled" <?php endif;?> class="input-text attribute-price validate-number template no-display" value="'{{pricing_value}}'"/>
```

with

```
<input id="__id___pricing" type="text" <?php if ($this->isAttributesPricesReadonly() || $this->getCanEditPrice() === false): ?> disabled="disabled" <?php endif;?> class="input-text attribute-price validate-number template no-display required-entry" value="'{{pricing_value}}'"/>
```